# How to add customer custom attribute data after customer creation in observer

Tags: magento2

I am doing something like this, but its saving custom attributes for the customer.

```
$customerInfo = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getId());
$customerInfo->setCustomAttribute('username1',$parameters['lsr_username']);
$customerInfo->setCustomAttribute('password',$parameters['password']);
$this->customerRepository->save($customerInfo));
```

Comment: have you created customer custom attributes programmatically ?

Comment: yes already created in setup

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right methods. It should work that way.

1) Make sure that you injected `customerRepository` correctly:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
){
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    ...
}
```

2) Check if your attributes `username1` and `password` are already created

3) Check if `$parameters['password']` and `$parameters['lsr_username']` are set correctly

Comment: yes i am doing same but custom attributes dont save

Comment: Are there any errors in your log-files? (var/log/debug.log or var/log/system.log)

Comment: nothing on it no error throws

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="yourObserverName" instance="company_name\module_name\Observer\Customersave" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And inside your observer file

```
<?php
namespace yourcompany_name\module_name\Observer;


use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class Customersave implements ObserverInterface
{



    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
protected $_customerFactory;

function __construct(CustomerFactory $customerFactory)
{
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;

}


public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $customerData = $observer->getCustomer();

        $customer = $this->_customerFactory->create()->load($customerData->getId());
        $customer->setCustomAttribute('somevalue');


           $customer->save();

    }
}
```

Or Save using below method

```
$customerInfo = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getId());

$customerData = $customerInfo->getDataModel();
            try {
                $customerData->setCustomAttribute('custom_field', $yourData);
                $customerInfo->updateData($customerData);
                $customerInfo->save();
                }
                catch(\Exception $ex){
                print_r(ex->getMessage());exit;
                }
```

Comment: I dont want to used model directly .I want to use api  data interface

Comment: then your method is correct. just debug your variables. try to use print_r(parameters).

Comment: Also remove generated folder and then try again

Comment: @SyedWaqasNabi see new code at the end of answer.

Comment: for repository i am using \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface

Comment: yes you can try with my new code. I hope it will work. This is also using customerRepositoryInterface. just add these lines in your code and replace custom_field with your custom attribute name

Comment: basically getDatamodel is not found in that method also #customerInfo->save() method also not found

Comment: customerInfo->save() is available in Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface.php file. Please check this file. Also  that interface returns data in data model then getDatamodel() should work.

Comment: https://github.com/thejinxters/magento2-testing/blob/master/app/code/Magento/Customer/Api/CustomerRepositoryInterface.php   for example its not here we have save but it require parameter to be pass